# Windows git difftool cannot parse extcmd path with spaces

Tags: git, msysgit, msys

In Windows, from the Git MSYS command line, I would like to run this command:

```
git difftool --extcmd=/C/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/Bcomp.exe -- file_to_diff.ext
```

I'm struggling to have the `extcmd` parameter parsed correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the correct way to write the command:

```
 git difftool -y --extcmd="'/C/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/BComp.exe'" -- file_to_diff.ext
```

**Notice the double quotes followed by single quotes.**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this only works with the first parameter.
Subsequent parameters, the ' is removed when displayed, but it is still cut off from the space.

Unfortunately I haven't found a solution anywhere else.

```
git difftool --extcmd="'/C/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe' /base:$LOCAL /mine:$REMOTE /basename:HEAD /minename:'xx yyyy'" --no-prompt "C:\......file-in-repo"

git difftool --extcmd="'/C/Program Files/TortoiseGit/bin/TortoiseGitMerge.exe' /base:$LOCAL /mine:$REMOTE /basename:HEAD '/minename:xx yyyy'" --no-prompt "C:\......file-in-repo"
```

Also, /minename: cannot contain round brackets.